# Why did Maul’s power fail this time?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, darth-maul

In the third season of *Star Wars Rebels*, Maul

> goes to Tatooine to kill Obi-Wan, and is easily killed.

There’s a great deal of thematic meaning to this, representing a transition from the flashy combat style employed by Obi-Wan in the prequels to the more economical version he uses in the original trilogy.

However, why was Maul unable to use his anger to save himself from dying, as he did before? Canonically, of course, this is how he survived his apparent death at the hands of Obi-Wan in *The Phantom Menace*:

> Q: How does Maul survive being cut in half?
>
> A: The power of anger! Maul draws on his master’s dark side lessons to
>   harness his rage and stay alive after Obi-Wan maims him in a duel on
>   Naboo. Rumor has it that his top half fell down a reactor shaft into a
>   trash container, which was then shipped to Lotho Minor.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*</sub>

- He was caught by surprise, but he had been caught by surprise before, too.
- He sustained less massive damage than before: instead of being cut in half, he was merely stabbed.

Why, then, did Maul die this time, while surviving much greater injury previously?

Comment: He obviously lost the will to live. You know what they say about poetry…

Comment: Perhaps because he's 30 years older and not as angry as before?

Comment: As Rebels is a kid's show, they don't show the exact location of Obi-Wan's stab/slice. I assume that he hit a more vital organ this time, like the heart.

Comment: It is likely Maul just was too old to struggle. In some of the episodes, he looks old and battered.

Comment: Maul’s secret is he’s not always angry.

Answer (score 4):

**He probably got hit in a vital organ.**

The angle of the shot makes it difficult to see exactly where he got hit, but it was clearly in the chest.

[image]

The official [Star Wars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/darth-maul) says as much.

> Maul's weapon was cut in two, as was his chest.

I disagree with the assertions that he "sustained less massive damage than before" and that he was "merely stabbed." Maul's tough, but probably not tough enough to survive without a functional heart/lung/whatever.

There's also the argument that he just wasn't as full of rage anymore. His final words feel much more sad and tired than angry, at least to me.